# find line in a file with specific words e.g. assert,Assert,ASSERTION, not combined words e.g. assertCount assert_Count

Tags: c#

I want to copy lines containing certain keywords e.g. assert or assertion but ignore line if it contains keyword combined with another word e.g. assertCount

I am able to copy lines with these keywords but don't know how to ignore if keyword is combined with another word

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stringFile);
                string line = null;
                //reading all text in a file
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {

                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) totalLines++;
                    if (line.IndexOf("assert", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        linesWithAssertions++;
                        fileObj.LogFileWriter(line);

                    }

                    else if (line.IndexOf("ASSERTION", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        linesWithAssertions++;
                        fileObj.LogFileWriter(line);
                    }

                }
```

I am using two separate functions for two keywords. Is there a way I can do this in one function only. And how to ignore line if keyword is combined with another word e.g. assertCount

Comment: maybe you could track case changing or _ symbol after matching part. If this will be not fluent enough, its a vocabularies area i think..

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `EqualsIgnoreCase("assert")`. Split each line into individual words and then use it. `line.Split(" ")` will split by space and return an array which will have all the words. Loop through the array and look for a match.

Comment: line.contains does same work but I want a function in which i can use all keywords

Comment: please elaborate more

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression.

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\bassert(ion)?\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    linesWithAssertions++;
}

bool match;
match = Regex.IsMatch("lorem assert ipsum", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");      // true
match = Regex.IsMatch("lorem assertion ipsum", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");   // true
match = Regex.IsMatch("lorem assert", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");            // true
match = Regex.IsMatch("assert lorem", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");            // true
match = Regex.IsMatch("assert", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");                  // true
match = Regex.IsMatch("lorem assertCount ipsum", @"\bassert(ion)?\b"); // false
match = Regex.IsMatch("loremassert", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");             // false
match = Regex.IsMatch("assertlorem", @"\bassert(ion)?\b");             // false
```

If you have more keywords, you can use this regex:

```cs
Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"\b(assert(ion)?|keyword2|keyword3)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success)
{
    string keyword = m.Groups[1].Value;
    if (keyword.StartsWith("assert", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        linesWithAssertions++;
    }
    else if (keyword.Equals("keyword2", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        linesWithKeyword2++;
    }
    else if (keyword.Equals("keyword3", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        linesWithKeyword3++;
    }
}
```